# Recommend chest exercises that will activate/help feel mind muscle connection

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, chest

I'm trying to build muscle (not much like the professionals but just to get into an aesthetic shape and feel the joy after working out). I've got everything set. I'm a little over a month into working out at home. But I'm not able to feel any mind muscle connection in the chest.
I tried exercises from YouTube. Single handed using resistance band to help activate the middle of the chest kinda worked a little. I felt a burn and a stretch/pressure at the sternum region. I even felt this a little during push-ups. But then I don't feel it continue/every time. I don't feel it enough. And I feel like I'm not doing things right. Does anyone know any sure shot exercises that could help me feel that contraction and help with muscle growth?

Also can someone describe how it really feels when all the muscle fibres of chest are activated? Where can I feel the burn? What are the focus points to keep in mind?
I can feel it only sometimes at the centre of the chest that's it.

Comment: Keep in mind it's harder to feel the muscle properly when it is still not well developed. I also struggle with chest and back muscles.

Comment: Also, if you're not doing a chest isolation movement, it could be that a smaller muscle (e.g. triceps) are giving out first before you feel the pectorals.

Comment: @Luciano Yup this was the first time I was actually doing a focused chest exercise for growing muscle. Earlier I depended only on push-ups, which I didn't do with good form as I've realised now.

Comment: Hard to beat bench press with a wide-ish grip for a pectoral emphasis. For what it's worth, I'm a tall, skinny guy who lifts pretty much less than anyone around me. If you can go to a gym and get comfortable lifting around the slabs of beef in the barbell section, that's awesome. There is a limit to resistance training with any but very heavy weights, that involve getting some fairly expensive equipment for your garage or, more affordably, going to a gym.

Answer (score 2):

For establishing muscle-mind connection I'd recommend light weight, moving very slowly, and doing exercises one arm at a time so you can put your other hand on the muscle you're trying to activate.

Chest flys might be a good choice:[image: chest fly]

Comment: I tried this and did feel it but not completely as shown in the illustration. But I did feel it around the anterior deltoid and a little of middle chest. And the centre region I already feel it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: lie down, tummy facing the ceiling, with your left hand upright (pointing to your ceiling). Keeping the rest of your body rigid, slowly move your left hand to the left side. You should feel a stretch in your chest, near where the muscle seems to go into your upper arm.

Slowly move your left hand back towards the middle of your body by consciously thinking of touching your left biceps to your left chest. Move your left hand across the midline of your body until your left biceps touches your chest. Your hands should remain as straight as possible. You should feel your entire chest muscles contract. Register how this feels and the next time you do your chest exercises, try to replicate this feeling.